# Ratio of two random variables

Tags: probability

Let $Z_i\sim \text{Normal}(0, I_n)$ independently for $i=1,\dots,n$. We define $X_n := \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$. Then we define $W_1=Z_1$ and for $i>1$,
\begin{align*}
W_{i} = 
\begin{cases}
W_{i-1}+Z_i, \text{ if } \|W_{i-1}+Z_i\|<\|W_{i-1}-Z_i\|;\\
W_{i-1}-Z_i, \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Let $Y_n = W_n$. I am interested in the asymptotic behavior of $\|Y_n\|/\|X_n\|$ as $n\to\infty$ in whatever types of convergence. We can assume for different $n$, the procedures are independent, i.e., we generate new $Z_i$'s for different $n$.

Comment: in this problem, what is $I_n$?

Comment: @gt6989b $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: So $Z_i \in \mathbb{R}^i$? Then how can you add them together?

Comment: @gt6989b $Z_i\in \mathbb R^n$. In other words, $[Z_1 \dots Z_n]$ is an $n\times n$ random matrix with i.i.d. unit normal entries.